# How to write math in kdenlive?

Tags: latex, kdenlive

I'm interested in create a math fashion video, and realized I need to type several math equations to display. If is a basic stuff this could be done with the title options in kdenlive and unicode characters.  But when the equations are a little bit complex like [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3827596/is-the-distributive-law-of-multiplication-valid-when-the-number-of-terms-are-var)  (the overbrace bracket), the thing starts to be very difficult and hard to mantain. So I want to know if there is a way to use LaTeX in kdenlive. Something of how the MathStackExchange forum posts work. Just using the symbol $ and in bewteen the LaTeX syntax and it generates the math equations.

Alternatively I tried to export from LaTeX the svg of the equations, but when passing to kdenlive it looks cutre.